# Nav view overboard and half-hidden on ionic + ibm mobile first

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I've been having this constant problem with nav-views on iOS 8.x, my css is as follows:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%
}
```

and my ionic platform initializers are these:

```
    StatusBar.hide();
    ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
```

Somehow on browsers it shows fine, but on any iOS mobile device the navigation bar is cropped.

example:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/AXUbxtF.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Not only the navbar. Your heading is too close to the status bar.

MobileFirst apps are bundled with their own CSS template, worklight.css.
I am guessing that by playing with the CSS rules there you will solve this.

The following is a common issue for Ionic with MobileFirst. I would try it: [Declaration of <!DOCTYPE html> does not work with Ionic's ion-nav-view in IBM MobileFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227204/declaration-of-doctype-html-does-not-work-with-ionics-ion-nav-view-in-ibm-mo)

Comment: thanks!! fiddling with the iphone css i noticed an odd padding:         body.wl_ios7{
 padding-top: 15pt;
} Changing it to 0pt solved the issue

Comment: Yes, that CSS will be applied to the CSS of apps running on iOS 7 and above.